# Orleans key and Database Records

Tags: actor, orleans

I'm just learning Microsoft Orleans, and I'm wondering how best to handle one of our scenarios. We will have a REST service that receives a request, which will eventually cause a new record to be created in an external system. This record will have a long Id value. We will then return this Id to the caller.

What is the recommendation for this scenario? Should there be a stateless grain that handles calling the external system and getting the Id. I'm thinking this "factory" grain would then create the grain with the id and provide the initial information to that grain (so it doesn't have to retrieve the data from the external store). However, I don't want it to attempt to read this information from the external store the first time it's activated.

Is there a recommendation on how to handle this using Microsoft Orleans grains?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do with the data for this record in the grain.
But generally it sounds like that your service should call into a regular grain (NOT stateless worker grain) and use the long id value as the grain primary key (there is no such thing as "create" grain, you just call it via the reference and it will be instantiate automatically).
The grain can then either read the data from the external storage or be explicitly passed some of parts of that data. Then if you need to serve futures requests about this data from memory, you will just direct them to this grain and it will serve them. The grain can also periodically (or upon some external message) decide to refresh/invalidate this data, if this data is mutable.

Comment: When the first request comes in, there is no Id. Instead, the call to the external system is to create a new instance, and the external system returns a new Id. So I won't have the Id until after the first call to the external system.

My grain will then return this Id to the client. So in the future the client can get status or make edit changes.

Comment: In such a case you can indeed use Stateless worker grains to pass the initial call to the external system and then use regular grains for future accesses.